# How to securely store files for use with web api

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, web

I have an application that serves as a books library. I have mysql database that contains all books(id, title, author, thumbnailURI, PdfURI). The actuall pdf book files are stored on separate server(http://files.hdesu.pl). Until now it worked liked that: 
-Client(website) gets list of books from Api and displays it to user.
-When user chooses specific book(by clicking on it), it goes to Details page passing choosen book ID.
-Details page requests data of that bookID from API, it gets back title, author, and paths to thumbnail and pdf.
-It then does ajax call to get those files from files server, and presents them to user.
Now my problem is that I need to somehow protect those files from anybody just getting them. Right now as long as you have URI you can download pdf, and I need them to be somehow restricted. How can I protect them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more of a architectural nature, but what I think you would want to do is:

1. Clients fetch PDFs via your API, not directly via a public url to your file storage. That way you can authenticate those requests in your API.
2. Restrict all access to your files except from the API

Comment: Ok, but how can I make my api send pdf file? I mean what type should the GetPDF controller return? In Asp net core

Comment: Check out [FileResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fileresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1).  I would provide links that basically proxy to the files you want.  Check security and return 403 status if they don't have access, stream the file ([FileStreamResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filestreamresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1)) if they have access.